# locate: using updatedb to create a database of directories only?

Tags: find, locate

GNU findutils' [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-updatedb.html#Invoking-updatedb) for `updatedb` says it has a `--findoptions` parameter. Does it mean I can specify a find-like option there to create a specific database for `locate`?

Like this, to include directories only:

```
updatedb --findoptions='-type d' --output='/Users/me/.config/locate/locatedb-dirs'
```

(I tried, however, and the resulting database was exactly the same as the one without this parameter. But may be it's just my syntax that was wrong?)

Comment: try to change the `--findoptions='-type f'`, recreate the database with `updatedb` and try to  `locate spool` and see if `/var/spool` shows up. If so, there is a chance this findoption isn't working since it's a dir. Also, are your using `locate` with the `-d /Users/me/.config/locate/locatedb-dirs` switch to use this manual output dir of yours?

Comment: @nwildner, OK, so I tested `updatedb` with and without `--findoptions='-type f'` on a folder with a lot subfolders / repositories (via `--localpaths='/Users/me/devel'`). And the result was two identical files (`diff` confirms). So I donno, may be we simply can't pass these options (`-type d` / `-type f`) to `updatedb`? :)

Comment: And, yeah, for the sake of experiment, I tried locate with `-d` switch pointing to this 'files-only' db, and it shows both files and folders, of course.

Comment: Maybe this thing does not work :P